# AlarmClock intent says "No apps can perform this action."

Tags: android, android-intent, alarm

I am trying to set an alarm in the alarm clock with an intent. I am using an Android One Phone (which has the unmodified OS) and have the Clock app installed (which came pre-installed) which allows setting alarm. Setting an alarm has worked in the past when I had used an AlarmManager and PendingIntent when I had to set the alarm in the background. That shows that my Clock app can respond to `AlarmClock` intents. But now when I am trying to send an intent from the foreground of my app, it says:

> No apps can perform this action.

*This is not from the stack trace, but a popup which is shown to users to choose which Clock app to choose to set the alarm (or which app to use in general for an intent)*

Here's the Activity's `onCreate()` code where I am calling it:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ...

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ...
        Utils.setAlarm(this, Utils.getLDT(epochTime).plusHours(8));
    }
}
```

Here's the `Utils#setAlarm` function that sends the intent:

```
public class Utils {

    public static void setAlarm(Context context, LocalDateTime alarmTimeDT) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(AlarmClock.ACTION_SET_ALARM);
        intent.putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_SKIP_UI, true);
        intent.putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_HOUR, alarmTimeDT.getHour());
        intent.putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_MINUTES, alarmTimeDT.getMinute());
        intent.putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_MESSAGE, "Good Morning");
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.startActivity(intent);
    }
    ...
}
```

This is the additional code that was used in the past for the same device and same Clock app. This is for cancelling an already set alarm, but the code used to set the old alarm was similar except for the cancelling part:

```
        //cancel old alarm
        AlarmManager alarmMgr = (AlarmManager) this.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        PendingIntent alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
                this, 0, i, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        if (alarmIntent != null) {
            alarmMgr.cancel(alarmIntent);
        } else {
            Log.i(TAG, "intent is null");
        }
```

**What am I doing wrong? Any help appreciated.**
*The below comments is just questioning and asking for more clarification on the question, which were done as asked for. So you may skip reading them*

Comment: "I have the default Clock app installed which allows setting alarm" -- there is no single "default Clock app" for Android. There are dozens, if not hundreds, of default clock apps, based on what the device manufacturer elected to ship. Perhaps your device has a clock app but no app that responds to this `Intent` action.

Comment: @CommonsWare By "default" I meant that there is the Clock app that cannot be uninstalled, at least in the unmodified OS. I am using Android One. I mentioned that: "It also has worked previously", which means that it can in fact respond to the Intent.

Comment: "I meant that there is the Clock app that cannot be uninstalled, at least in the unmodified OS" -- and there are dozens, if not hundreds, of these, based on what the device manufacturer elected to ship. In your case, AFAIK, Google controls that on Android One devices. Is your error message coming in the form of a stack trace? If so, you might want to edit your question and include the complete stack trace. You might also want to show your scenario where you believe that your code works, so we can compare and contrast what is working for you and what is not.

Comment: " there are dozens, if not hundreds..." how does that help with the question when I mentioned that it has worked in the past? Of course I was talking about my case - the Android One Phone I have. There's no error message in the stack trace, this is from the small popup (usually shown to choose which app to use to complete the action) the app shows on start, clarified in the post. The code where it worked is all same, it just used an AlarmManager with PendingIntent. Still, added.

Comment: "how does that help with the question when I mentioned that it has worked in the past?" -- unless your app will only run on your own device, you have to take into account that other users will have different devices with different characteristics. "this is from the small popup (usually shown to choose which app to use to complete the action)" -- that's very strange. If there really was no app to handle the `Intent`, you would crash with an `ActivityNotFoundException`. Since you are not, something *is* handling the `Intent`.

Comment: "The code where it worked is all same, it just used an AlarmManager with PendingIntent" -- other than both code snippets having "alarm" in them, they seem unrelated. The `AlarmManager` code snippet is not calling `Utils.setAlarm()`, for example. Where is `i` coming from? Is that an `AlarmClock.ACTION_SET_ALARM` `Intent`?

Comment: "unless your app will only run on your own device" no it won't, but for now I am focusing on the device on hand before thinking for other devices. "that's very strange" don't know why it is, because almost every other app uses it, most commonly when sharing something (it might be called something other than a "popup" technically). I have added the code for `Utils.setAlarm()`. It is intuitive that the code for creating the intent should be the same and that `i` is that intent. No it was for `ACTION_DISMISS_ALARM`, which I mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> No apps can perform this action.

This happens when you don't have the required permission to set the alarm.

From [AlarmClock reference](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/AlarmClock):

> Applications that wish to receive the ACTION_SET_ALARM and ACTION_SET_TIMER Intents should create an activity to handle the Intent that **requires the permission com.android.alarm.permission.SET_ALARM.**

Request the `SET_ALARM` permission:

```
<mainfest
    ...
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.alarm.permission.SET_ALARM"/>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Thanks! This was the problem!